# how to add child to an opened group in expandabllistview on onChildClikListener event

Tags: android

as a beginner in android, i am facing a lot of problems. One of the problem is that, while adding child to the opened group. The child is getting added but not to the respective group but to all the groups. How can i achieve to add to the respective group. Please anyone share your knowledge, if you have ever faced this kind of issue.
     Below is my onChildClickListener code.

1. ```
   expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                       long id) {


           developmentType.add("grocery"); // this is the another child which i am adding
           dataList.put(groupList.get(groupPosition), developmentType); // this is hashmap, where respective group and child is passed
           expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
               return false;
           }
       });
   ```

   Here is my adapter class

   ```
   public class TimeEntryExpandableListAdapter extends                       BaseExpandableListAdapter{
   private Context context;
   private List<String> paretnList;
   private List<String> weekDaysList;
   private HashMap<String, List<String>> childList;
   private List<String> monthAndDays;
   private ImageView addIconId;
   private TextView totalTimeId;

   private BaseExpandableListAdapter bela;
   private long groupId;
   private Object group;
   private ArrayList<TimeEntryDetailData<Object>> mParent;
   private LayoutInflater inflater;
   private String groupName;

   public TimeEntryExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String>   monthAndDays,
                                 List<String> weekDaysList, List<String>  paretnList, HashMap<String,List<String>> childList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.monthAndDays = monthAndDays;
        this.weekDaysList = weekDaysList;
        this.paretnList = paretnList;
        this.childList = childList;
   ```

   }

   ```
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
     return this.paretnList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
     return this.childList.get(this.paretnList.get(i)).size();
    }

     @Override
      public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
      return this.paretnList.get(listPosition);
     }

     @Override
     public Object getChild(int listPosition, int listDetailPosiion) {
      return      this.childList.get(this.paretnList.get(listPosition)).get(listDetailPosiion);
    }

     @Override
     public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
      return listPosition;
     }

     @Override
     public long getChildId(int listPosition, int listDetailPosiion) {
      return listDetailPosiion;
     }

      @Override
      public boolean hasStableIds() {
       return false;
      }

      @Override
      public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded, View       convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       String dayOfWeek = (String) getDay(listPosition);
       String monthAndDayValue = (String) getMonthAndDays(listPosition);
       String[] unFormatedValue = monthAndDayValue.split(":");
       String monthName = unFormatedValue[0];
       String dayName = unFormatedValue[1];
       if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)    this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView =    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_time_entry_group_view, null);
       } 

        TextView grpDayNameId = (TextView)    convertView.findViewById(R.id.listGrpDayNameId);
        TextView grpMonthNameId = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.listGrpMonthNameId);
        TextView monthTxtId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.monthTxtId);
        TextView currentDateId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.currentDateId);
         totalTimeId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalTimeId);
        grpDayNameId.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

         currentDateId.setText(dayOfWeek); // setting the date on the left left   side of expandalblelistview.
        grpDayNameId.setText(dayName); // setting day name
       //grpMonthNameId.setText(monthName); // setting month name
        monthTxtId.setText(monthName); // setting month name under the   date   displaying field to the left
       return convertView;
   ```

   }

   ```
      @Override
      public View getChildView(int listPosition, int listDetailPosiion,   boolean       isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
      final String listText = (String) getChild(listPosition,    listDetailPosiion);
      if (convertView == null ) {
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)  this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_time_entry_child_view, null);

       addIconId = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addIconId);
       groupId =  getGroupId(listPosition);
       groupName = getGroup(listPosition).toString();
       totalTimeId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalTimeId);
       //addIconId.setOnClickListener(this);
       group = getGroup(listPosition);

     }

     return convertView;
   ```

   }

   ```
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: can we see more code? Preferably how the adapter code looks like.

Comment: Hi i have added the adapter part code. can you suggest, where the problem lies?

Comment: Try using **expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** instead of **expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();**

Comment: expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated() both of these method updating the new child to all the group available in my expandablelistview.

Comment: I don't think your new item is being added to all your datasets, but that your ListView and Adapter implementation have problems rendering. Have you tried using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) and **ViewHolders** instead? You could also try creating a data model that holds your items so you get rid of the lot of lists in your adapter.

Comment: let me try RecyclerView once. Thanks for your help.